# Loading modules in JBoss 7.x

Tags: java, jboss7.x

this time I'm figthing against JBoss 7.1. My simple application, something.jar, has this jboss-deployment-structure.xml:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="deployment.EarApp.ear.Stuff1-1.0.jar" />
            <module name="deployment.EarApp.ear.Stuff2-1.0.jar" />
            <module name="deployment.EarApp.ear.Somelib-1.0.jar" />
            <module name="org.apache.commons.io"/>
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Compile, build and depoly goes fine. But when jboss execute this line

```
BodyPart bodypart = new MimeBodyPart();
bodypart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(new FileDataSource(new File(attachment))));
bodypart.setFileName(FilenameUtils.getName(attachment)); //this one!!
m.addBodyPart(bodypart);
```

I got this error

```
...(more)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils from [Module "deployment.EarApp.ear.Stuff2-1.0.jar:main" from Service Module Loader]
...(more)
```

What's wrong with it? Why my application can't see apache commons io?

Comment: I don't know if this will work or not, but have you tried putting `export="true"` after `name="org.apache.commons.io"`?

Comment: Where is the code you're trying to execute located? In one of your dependencies or the deployment that contains the `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`

Comment: @disrvptor Yes I tryed and deploy fails. Remove export="true" and deploy goes fine.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins you're right. Into `%jboss%/standalone/deployments` are `EarApp.ear` and `something.jar`. Exactly in the same directory.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand fully, but it sounds like you might need to add the org.apache.commons.io dependency on the something.jar if that's where you're using the FilenameUtils. You can add it in another jboss-deployment-structure.xml in that library or in the `MANIFEST.MF` of that library.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins yes you're right, that's what I did. The `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` I show is exactly the one inside `something.jar/META-INF`. I was unclear, sorry.

Comment: Just to be clear, the `jboss-deployment-strcuture.xml` is in `EarApp.ear/lib/Stuff2-1.0.jar/META-INF` correct?

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins no, the jboss-deployment-structure.xml I post is inside `something.jar/META-INF`.

Comment: Ah, okay that's the problem then. Try adding either a `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` or a `MANIFEST.MF` entry (Dependencies: org.apache.commons.io) to the Stuff2-1.0.jar.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins yes. That's the way. But I did it on the wrong module. JBoss told me in it's error log. It was Stuff2-1.0.jar that needs commons.io, not something.jar. Thankyou, you point me on the right way to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well,

Stuff2 seems to be a jar within the EARApp standalone deployment - thus Stuff2 (or EARApp) needs to handle it's own deps, you cannot make that right from the deployment structure of "Some application". Everything is isolated these days.

So simplest solution in your case might be to add a similar jboss-deployment-structure.xml to the META-INF folder of the Stuff2 jar (or EARApp if also Stuff1 needs IO files), and make sure it has a reference to `<module name="org.apache.commons.io"/>`. Or, as I'd prefer, instead make sure that your build tool (Maven?) adds a `dependencies` attribute to MANIFEST.MF or Stuff2.jar (or EARApp) to org.apache.io and thus you'd not need the jboss-deployment-structure.xml-file.

That being said, this does not seem to be very JEE conformant - you are from "Some Application" (war, ear?) referencing jars inside other EARS? That sounds like trouble to me! You probably have a good reason why you went that direction, but you could of course consider repackage "Some Application" to a JEE standard way. If you'd drop both the Stuff2 jar and Commons IO jar into the `lib` folder of "Some Application" you wouldn't need to think JBoss Modules, JBoss descriptor files or even standard descriptor files.

br,
Jens

Comment: True. The problem was I added module dependency org.apache.commons.io to the wrong module. It was Stuff2-1.0.jar that use commons.io. Your argue is also correct to me, so I mark this as correct answer.